# CodeIgniter extending file causes http 500

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter

If I extend below file **OR** just autoload it in autoload.php all I get is http 500 and sometimes empty output. MYControllerInterface.php is located under application/libraries .

I've chmod'ed the whole directory (recursivly) to 0777. I've created a .htaccess with RewriteEngine On and Off in the root directory.

I've commented out everything from { to } in MYcontrollerInterface...

I've tried removed the ending ?>

I've checked that mod_rewrite is enabled in php config... This is so mysterious!

```
<?php 
class MYcontrollerInterface extends CI_Controller {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        //$this->load->helper('url');
    }   

    function build_page($main_content_view, $data) {
        /*
        $this->load->view('header', $data);    
        //$this->load->view('content', $data);      
        //$this->load->view($main_content_view, $data, true);
        $this->load->view('footer', $data);   
        */      
        echo 'apa';
    }   
}

/* End of file MycontrollerInterface.php */
/* Location: ./application/controllers/MYcontrollerInterface.php */
?>
```

application/logs/log-2012-04-12.php :

```
DEBUG - 2012-04-12 13:21:22 --> Config Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2012-04-12 13:21:22 --> Hooks Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2012-04-12 13:21:22 --> Utf8 Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2012-04-12 13:21:22 --> UTF-8 Support Enabled
DEBUG - 2012-04-12 13:21:22 --> URI Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2012-04-12 13:21:22 --> Router Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2012-04-12 13:21:22 --> Output Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2012-04-12 13:21:22 --> Security Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2012-04-12 13:21:22 --> Input Class Initialized
```

below keeps repeating:

```
DEBUG - 2012-04-12 13:21:22 --> Global POST and COOKIE data sanitized
DEBUG - 2012-04-12 13:21:22 --> Language Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2012-04-12 13:21:22 --> Loader Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2012-04-12 13:21:22 --> Controller Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2012-04-12 13:21:22 --> Final output sent to browser
DEBUG - 2012-04-12 13:21:22 --> Total execution time: 0.0320
DEBUG - 2012-04-12 13:21:38 --> Config Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2012-04-12 13:21:38 --> Hooks Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2012-04-12 13:21:38 --> Utf8 Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2012-04-12 13:21:38 --> UTF-8 Support Enabled
DEBUG - 2012-04-12 13:21:38 --> URI Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2012-04-12 13:21:38 --> Router Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2012-04-12 13:21:38 --> Output Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2012-04-12 13:21:38 --> Security Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2012-04-12 13:21:38 --> Input Class Initialized
```

Comment: You need to look at `apache` and `codeigniter` logs, to find out, where the problem is.

Comment: where can I find those? on mac os x

Comment: Try to set up xdebug and set some break points through your code. That should give you a better clue of what's going wrong.

Comment: Apache logs are usually located in `/var/log/apache2/`. About CI error logs: http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/191508/#903948 . 500 error usually means, there's a php error/exception.

Comment: put this file in system/libraries folder

Comment: `MYcontrollerInterface.php` should be in `controller` folder. Not library

Comment: I tried putting it in the `controller__s__` folder, made no difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are extending a controller (which is a core class) it needs to go in /application/core.

Also check your prefix, the CI2 standard is MY_ (check your $config['subclass_prefix'] at line  109).

***UPDATE*** An extended controller must be called MY_Controller (as per the loader class).

You would then use it like...

```
class foo extends MY_Controller {
    function __construct() {
        parent::construct();
    }
}
```

Comment: doesn't make any difference though :(

Comment: If you want to make multiple extended controllers add all the classes to the one MY_Controller file (the same goes for extending models)

Answer (score -1):

You can put this file in the `system/libraries` folder and try extending it.

Comment: First you shouldnt put anything to system folder , second that file must be inside controller folder, not library